# Resetting a while True loop

Tags: python-3.x

How do you reset a while True loop. For example this is my code:

```
x=True
while x==True:
    print ("Random Text")
    randomtext= input()
    if randomtext == "yes":
        print ("hi")
        x=False
    elif randomtext == "no":
        print("This is supposed to reset the loop")
        #resets loop and prints Random Text again
    print ("hi")
    if x==True:
        print ("placeholder text")
        input()
```

I want it to reset the loop if "randomtext" is equal to yes. I want to reset it it in the middle of the loop. This is a very simple question but this is getting in my programming. Thank you.

Comment: There's no need to compare `x` with `True` in the `while` condition. Just `while x` works just as well. On the other hand, sometimes you may want to do `while True` (with no `x`), which means to loop indefinitely (until there's a `break`). From your title I was expecting that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that by resetting the loop you mean jumping code until reaching the start of the loop again. This is done with the "continue" keyword.

```
 if randomtext == "yes":
   continue
```

If you actually meant breaking out of the loop, you should instead use the "break" keyword.